# LBJ Quote - did he actually say this?

Tags: united-states, president

“I’ll have those niggers voting Democratic for the next 200 years.” —Lyndon B. Johnson to two governors on Air Force One

Did LBJ really say that? I can't find any objective authoritative sources to back this up..

Comment: This belongs more in Skeptics SE than Politics SE.

Comment: It does sound [in character](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1rIDmDWSms) for LBJ.

Comment: See this Reddit thread for an insightful dissection of the high probability and context of the quote: https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/2088gl

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source of the quote is Robert Kessler's book "Inside the White House". The guy is known for scooping tabloid sounding but eventually 100% true stories (Secret Service scandals). Whether you trust him on that quote or not is your call - the book doesn't list any sources that a historian would consider impeccable; but as far as I'm aware he's never been proven wrong.

Comment: Thanks, DVK! Here's a link with this quote from a review of his book: http://www.amazon.com/Inside-White-House-Kessler/product-reviews/1433244985/ref=cm_cr_dp_text?ie=UTF8&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=byRankDescending#RCU0REO851XT6

Comment: Ronald Reagan secretly took orders from aliens.  Prove me wrong!

Comment: @SamIam - are you a well known journalist known for many conspiracy sounding but true scoops and access to people in the know?

Comment: @DVK Yes I am.  Prove me wrong!

Comment: @SamIam - you have no references to back that up. Kessler does.

Answer (score -4):

So, it seems in this case, we'd have to take Kesslers word for it. We can neither prove or disprove this by any independent means. 
  On the other hand, the incredibly brilliant "samIam" thinks that someone's account (who has been found to be a reliable source) is comparable to receiving orders from aliens. To him, this is probably an air-tight analogy.
  According to this logic, we can't be entirely sure that Thomas Jefferson authored much of the Declaration of Independence because we have to merely rely on others' accounts that he did. You know..."prove to me that it wasn't aliens who really wrote it..."
   Apart from that, if anyone is interested in a recorded phone call of LBJ using the N****R word in reference to black voters voting for the Democratic party; here you go:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r1rIDmDWSms

Comment: Commentary needs to be separated from the answer.